# git branch hierarchy issue

Tags: git, github

I am still pretty noob in Git but probably after reading articles after articles, I seem to have raise doubt in my understanding and I am not sure if I am understanding it right...

- Anyway I have 2 branches, Master and Develop (both created using git
  branch) As I created the Master branch first, followed by Develop,
  can I presume that this 2  branches are 2 standalone branches (see
  below) or is Develop under the Master?

  ```
  Stand-Alone?    Hierarchy?
  Master  --      | Master
  Develop --      |   \-- Develop
  ```

I was under the impression it should be standalone, until when I run `git show-branch`, it is displaying the results as (Notice the space in front of the [Master]):

```
[Develop] Creation of new Branch 
 [Master] Build of new Project
```

- If I am to create new (feature) branches, using Develop as my base,do I need to set it to the Develop branch first, otherwise can it be done from any branches?
- Lastly is it possible to view the branches in the terminal in the following format:

  ```
  Master
     Develop
        newBranch01
           ...
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2 standalone branches (see below) or is Develop under the Master?

Neither.

Commits matter.  Branch names don't.  Focus on the commits.  Branch and tag names are an afterthought, a trivial convenience.  `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` and `git show-branch` will show you the history in two different representations, each has advantages.

Comment: Okay... So, as to my second, since I don't suppose third is possible to be attempted in the terminal, do I need to be on that particular branch in the first place? Adding on, is `git checkout -b newBranch develop` any similar to `git checkout -b newBranch`? Seen quite some examples using either one of them so as to branch out from the branch that the user needed

Comment: When you commit, your last-committed-or-currently-checked-out commit (git always updates `HEAD` to refer to that) is the new commit's parent.  So far as the commit history is concerned, branch names don't matter at all.  Being "on a branch" only means if `HEAD` is attached to a branch ref, that branch ref will as a convenience be updated to point to the new commit as well.  (you can also tie other effects to a branch -- you can supply per-branch defaults for pull/fetch/push/many others, for instance, see the `git config` docs if you want a taste.)