# Branch hierarchy in local Git

Tags: git, github

I'm learning basic Git. Created a basic directory (1 empty folder), initialized Git, created remote repo and pushed the empty folder to have the local + remote repos synced up.

Now I'm exploring branches; I want to create a new branch under master and make basic changes (e.g. adding more sub-folders, empty .txt files) to the branch, and then commit, merge, etc. these changes.

When I create a branch, it's on top of the master branch in the list of all branches on Terminal (see image). Is this simply syntactical, or does the order in which branches are presented mean something?

I'd like the new branch to be subordinate (so to speak) to the master branch.

I read another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466882/git-branch-hierarchy-issue) that states that 'Commits matter, branch names don't'; is that the answer to my question as well?

[Branch hierarchy as per Git in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrwyF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a bit to unpack in your question.

First off, let's focus on your immediate question:

The branch names don't matter -- the ordering you're seeing is alphabetical.

However, there's a couple of small misconceptions that come up here, that we can walk through:

First the small one: git doesn't track empty directories. If you try to add it to your repository, nothing will happen. This might lead you to some confusion if you're not aware of it.

Now the bigger one: there's no "hierarchy" of branches in git. In the abstract, you can think of every branch as a completely independent copy of the repository. Any hierarchy of repositories is purely a convention of the users of the repository. git itself has no concept of branch hierarchies.

Answer (score 3):

Branches don't have a hierarchical relationship. A branch is just a label for a commit id.  You can have multiple branches all pointing at the same commit, and you can have branches that contain completely unrelated history.

The order in which branches are displayed in the output of `git branch` is not meaningful; it's just a list of branches sorted alphabetically.

The [Git branches in a nutshell](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell) chapter of the Git book is good reading on this topic.

Comment: How come that my push on github gets rejected with such a message? `! [remote rejected]   translations/update-translations -> translations/update-translations (cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/translations/update-translations': 'refs/heads/translations' exists; cannot create 'refs/heads/translations/update-translations')`
This sounds kinda hierarchical